# How to cope with errors made by returning ChangeNotifierProvider while using riverpod?

Tags: flutter, dart

I was implementing a sign-up page in my app and when I ran the code, there was an error in my debug console saying "Exception caught by gesture - Bad state: No ProviderScope found"

I immediately found out that the problem was that I didn't wrap the entire application with ProviderScope.

So I tried to fix that issue with the solution but by wrapping the entire application with ProviderScope, there were 4 more errors from `return ChangeNotifierProvider` in `_MyAppState` class.

This is how the situation looks right now.
[image: error]
[image: error2]

Here are the two versions of the code that I've been working on right now. The latter one is the code that makes the 4 errors.

## main.dart

```
import 'package:app/models/challenge_model.dart';
import 'package:app/side_menu/sidebar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ChallengeModel(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: const SideBar(),
        theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.lightGreen),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## main.dart (4 errors occurred)

```
import 'package:app/models/challenge_model.dart';
import 'package:app/side_menu/sidebar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(
    // Enabled Riverpod for the entire application
    const ProviderScope(
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ChallengeModel(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: const SideBar(),
        theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.lightGreen),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```